PMD Designer. The environment variable JAVAFX_HOME is missing
I installed the PMD using the following command:
brew install pmd

After installation I tried to run the PMD Designer:
pmd designer

And I got the following error: The environment variable JAVAFX_HOME is missing.
Please tell me how to fix the problem and launch the PMD designer (I assume that homebrew should have installed all the necessary dependencies for the PMD)?

A possible solution could be the following:

Download JavaFX.
Unzip the archive.
Set the environment variable: export JAVAFX_HOME=/path/to/unzipped-dir
Run PMD Designer: pmd designer

